# Chrome Developer Tools > Find in Source

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any way to do a "Find in HTML Source" (like the "Find in Styles" functionality for CSS) using Chrome Developer Tools?

And I'm not talking about doing a View Source then Finding the element.

I'm looking for something that's a bit more integrated into the tools.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to right-click anywhere and press "Inspect Element" to bring you straight to the element clicked in the HTML.